# Absolute Positioned img inside absolute div doesnt position as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have the following html

```
   <div class="banner_area_internal">
    <div class="banner_wrapper_internal" id="overlay_field">
        <img src="images/internal_banner_holder.png" />
        <img class="internal_banner" src="images/about-banner.jpg" />
        <div id="overlay">
        <img class="internal_banner_overlay" src="images/about-banner_hover.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
   .banner_area_internal {
margin-top:10px;
width:100%;
height:250px;}

   .banner_wrapper_internal {
height:250px;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto}

   .banner_wrapper_internal p {
font-size:30px;
color:#ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
margin:0px 300px;
display:block}

   .internal_banner {
position:relative;
top:-235px;
left:15px;
z-index:-2;
}

   .internal_banner_overlay {
position:absolute;
top:-25px;
left:15px;
z-index:-2;
}

    #overlay{
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
width:340px;
height:200px;
z-index:-1;
border:2px #aeaeae solid;
     }

    #overlay_field
   {
position: relative;
width:1000px;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
    }
```

and the following script as mentioned by @rkw

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#overlay_field").hover(function(){


$("#overlay").show(); //Show tooltip
}, function() {
    $("#overlay").hide(); //Hide tooltip
})

  $('#overlay_field').mousemove(function(e){
$("#overlay").css({left:e.pageX-360, top:e.pageY-280});
  });

  });
```

The Effect I'm trying to achieve here is:

An image appears in as a banner "internal_banner"

When the mouse hovers over this image(or rather "overlay_field") a small div appears which follows the mouse. Now the contents of the div is another image "internal_banner_overlay"

I want this image to be positioned exactly as "internal_banner", i.e stay in the same place so it appears like the mouse let's you see another underlying image. The problem is the image doesn't stay at one place, it positions within the div and moves with the mouse rather than the document even though it's position is set to absolute.

In simple words, when the mouse moves over the banner area, it should appear like the cursor changed to a small box that let's you see through the banner at another image.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to create a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: whenever you have an absolute positioned element and want it to stay in the container, the container must have a position of relative

Comment: @fbynite I tried making a Jsfiddle but some reason it would not work..

Comment: @CodyGuldner It's exactly the opposite that I'm trying to achieve, the parent element will move with the mouse, so I want the image to position relative to the document ( basically ignore the parent)..

Answer (score 0):

Just add the temp banner in the upper div and change its opacity on mouseover and mouseout events.

```
<div class="banner_area_internal">
    <div class="banner_wrapper_internal" id="overlay_field">
        <img src="abcd.png" />
        <img class="internal_banner permBanner" src="permBanner.png" />
        <img alt="" src="tempBanner.jpg" id="temp" style="height: 250px; width: 1000px; opacity: 0; position: absolute">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#overlay_field").hover(function(){


$("#overlay").show(); //Show tooltip
}, function() {
    $("#overlay").hide(); //Hide tooltip
})

  $('#overlay_field').mousemove(function(e){

  var width = 250;
  var height = 250;
  var left = parseInt(e.pageX)-parseInt(pageXOffset);
  var top = parseInt(e.pageY)-parseInt(pageYOffset);
  var a = document.getElementById("temp");
  a.style.opacity = 1;
  a.style.left = "0px";
  a.style.top = "0px";
  a.style.clip = "rect("+top+","+(left+100)+","+(top+100)+","+left+")";

  });
});
```

**Style**

```
 .banner_area_internal {
margin-top:10px;
width:100%;
height:250px;}
   .banner_wrapper_internal {
height:250px;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto}
   .banner_wrapper_internal p {
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px 300px;
    display:block;
}
   .internal_banner {
position:relative;
top:-235px;
left:15px;
z-index:-2;
}

   .internal_banner_overlay {
position:absolute;
top:-25px;
left:15px;
z-index:-2;
}

    #overlay{
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
width:250px;
height:250px;
border:2px #0000bb solid;
     }

    #overlay_field
   {
position: absolute;
width:1000px;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
    }​
    #temp{position:absolute;}
```

**Alternate:**
Or alternatively you can add and remove the temporary banner on the mouseover and mouseout events.

Comment: Tried it.. doesnt seem to work.. and I think the code you provided would simply replace the perm banner with the temp banner right??? what I want the the perm banner to constantly be visible and only a section of the temp banner (the small div that follows the mouse) to show the temp banner... Hope's I've made it easy to understand...

Comment: @TDsouza: Ok, you want to show the clipped part of the temporary banner with the size equal to the overlay div? And only the portion where the overlay div is present?